# How to show scrollbar without providing fixed height to inner container with outer container having position fixed

Tags: html, css, reactjs, scrollbar, css-position

I want to show scrollbar without providing fixed height to inner container with outer container having position fixed.
I am facing an issue that if I provide to fixed height to the innerContainer. And when I check the responsiveness and change the height of the window the outerContainer with position fixed hides the content of innerContainer.

```
// OUTER CONTAINER
<div style={ { width: "250px", zIndex: 5, position: "fixed", right: "2rem" } }>
    <div style={ { width:"100%, height: "100px" } }>
        // having some other content
    </div>
    // INNER CONTAINER
    <div style={ { width: "100%", height: "400px", overflowY: "auto" } }>
       // overflowing content inside the container
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there any solution please help me. I will be very thnkfull for time and help.

Answer (score 0):

add to the outer container:

```
display: "flex", flexDirection: "column"
```

and then you can remove the height of the inner container.

Comment: No it doesn't work. It doesn't show the scrollbar

Comment: try to add `height: "100%"` to the outer container.
https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-kare-6uhzj?file=/src/Component.tsx